# How to make ag-grid simply fit inside a contaner

Tags: ag-grid

I am getting started with react ag-grid, and it seems that the tutorials the provide have hardcoded with and height:

```
            <div
                className="ag-theme-balham"
                style={{ height: '200px', width: '600px' }}
            >
                <AgGridReact
                    columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
                    rowData={this.state.rowData}>
                </AgGridReact>
            </div>
```

If I remove width and height specs, the grid simply doesnt show up.
I really dont want to have some magical size numbers.  If I am using Bootstrap or Material CSS, and I have the notion of a "centered container" class with some controls in it, I would like the grid to be of that container size -- is that possible?  I dont know CSS at all -- kind of cutting and pasting examples, but essentially, I want a series of input controls, centered on my page vertically -- and ag-grid among them.  this doesnt seem to be an issue with the "standard" html inputs/buttons, but ag-grid is a different beast. thank you

Comment: I have been using height: 100% and it fits the container. I believe the standard html inputs and buttons already have a height defined for them.

Comment: @Aamir, can you please show me what you are actually doing?  Your suggestion doesnt work for me, perhaps we are talking about different things.   thank you

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<div style={{height: '500px', width: '100%', position: 'absolute'}}>
    <div className="ag-theme-balham" style={{height: '100%'}}>
        <AgGridReact gridOptions={gridOptions}/>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the grid height will always be the same as outer div height.